# Shorthand way to construct JS object with variable property name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-objects

Is there a shorthand way to create an object with a property field variable?

Say I have the variable `PROP.Todo.PRIORITY = 'priority'` and then, using [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) in this example, I want to [save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) this property, how can I avoid having to create a new object, assigning it to some variable and then set the property?

I want to achieve this:

```
var tmpObj = {};
tmpObj[PROP.Todo.PRIORITY] = "high";
this.model.save(tmpObj);
```

I've tried something like this, which was unsuccessful:

```
this.model.save(({}[PROP.Todo.PRIORITY] = "high"));
```

Any suggestions? I'm going to be writing a lot of long-hand object declarations otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an easier way to create the object, how about using a helper function?

```
function obj(prop, value) {
  var o = {};
  o[prop] = value;
  return o;
}

this.model.save(obj(PROP.Todo.PRIORITY, "high"));
```

I'm not sure I understand the latter part of your question:

> I'm going to be creating a lot of temporary objects otherwise.

You'll have to create an object in any case, and I doubt creating objects is a performance issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I like this solution, although the other answer will probably be my route of choice. And yes, my wording could have been better; I don't mean 'temporary', what I meant was a lot of declaring of new objects would be required...i.e. lots of code bloat, it wasn't a concern over performance.

Answer (score 4):

If you save only one parameter, `Model.save` has a an alternative way of receiving arguments, `(key,value,options)`

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

> **save** *model.save([attributes], [options])*
>   [...] As with set, you may pass individual keys and values instead of a hash. [...]

which means you could write your example as

```
this.model.save(PROP.Todo.PRIORITY, "high");
```

If you want to save multiple properties simultaneously, you will have to write a temporary object.

Comment: +1 for reading the docs. :) Didn't realize there was a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I'll go with. However I think I'm going to accept the other answer seeing as in future, if people arrive here via Google, it more directly answers the title of the question..hope you understand!

Comment: Worth noting; I was using the [TODO MVC webapp](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) and it uses Backbone `0.5.0-pre` which doesn't support the suggested way of saving attributes. The latest version (`0.9.2` at time of writing) does however.

Comment: @Ed. Good catch, I had forgotten that this syntax came with 0.9.0